# Issues performing network I/O in a NodeJS worker thread

Tags: node.js, multithreading, axios, worker, worker-pool

I have a script that will download thousands of files from a server, perform some CPU-intensive calculations on those files, and then upload the results somewhere. As an added level of complexity, I want to limit the number of concurrent connections to the server where I'm downloading the files.

To get the CPU-intensive calculations off the event thread, I leveraged [workerpool by josdejong](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool). I also figured I could take advantage of the fact that only a limited number of threads will be spun up at any given time to limit the number of concurrent connections to my server, so I tried putting the network I/O in the worker process like so (TypeScript):

```
import Axios from "axios";
import workerpool from "workerpool";

const pool = workerpool.pool({
    minWorkers: "max",
});

async function processData(file: string) {
    console.log("Downloading " + file);
    const csv = await Axios.request<IncomingMessage>({
        method: "GET",
        url: file,
        responseType: "stream"
    });
    console.log(csv);
    // TODO: Will process the file here
}

export default async function (files: string[]) {
    const promiseArray: workerpool.Promise<Promise<void>>[] = [];
    // Only processing the first file for now during testing
    files.slice(0, 1).forEach((file) => {
        promiseArray.push(pool.exec(processData, [file]));
    });
    await Promise.allSettled(promiseArray);
    await pool.terminate();
}
```

When I compile and run this code I see the message "Downloading test.txt", but after that I don't see the following log statement (`console.log(csv)`)

I've tried various modifications on this code including removing the `responseType`, removing `await` and just inspecting the `Promise` that's returned by Axios, making the function non-async, etc. No matter what it seems to always crash on the `Axios.request` line

Are worker threads not able to open HTTP connections or something? Or am I just making a silly mistake?

Comment: You have ZERO error handling so errors are probably being thrown, but you're not logging them.  Put `try/catch` around your `await` statements and log the errors.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the good lead. I originally prototyped my code without worker threads and I have a global error handler (a massive try/catch around the whole program) - I didn't realize that it wouldn't catch errors thrown in worker threads. It's saying "axios_1 is not defined". So I guess imports on the event thread don't persist on the worker thread.

Comment: If this is regular nodejs worker threads, then they are entirely separate Javascript VMs.  They don't share any code or variables.  It is possible to set up some shared memory between threads and the main event loop, but that's raw memory, not variables or imports or anything like that.  Think of each thread as completely separate that communicates with the main thread via messaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not getting to this line of code:

```
console.log(csv);
```

Then, either the `Axios.request()` is never fulfilling its promise or that promise is rejecting.   You have no error handling at all in any of these functions so if it was rejecting, you wouldn't know and wouldn't be logging the problem.  As a starter, I would suggest you instrument your code so you can log any rejections:

```
async function processData(file: string) {
    try {
        console.log("Downloading " + file);
        const csv = await Axios.request<IncomingMessage>({
            method: "GET",
            url: file,
            responseType: "stream"
        });
        console.log(csv);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);          // log an error
        throw e;                 // propagate rejection/error
    }

}
```

As a general point of code design, you should be catching and logging any possible promise rejection at some level.  You don't have to catch them all at the lowest calling level as they will propagate up through returned promises, but you do need to catch any possible rejection somewhere and, for your own development sanity, you will want to log it so you can see when it happens and what the error is.

Comment: Before refactoring my code to use worker threads I was actually catching everything in a global `try/catch` in my index.ts file. I didn't realize that worker threads would need their own error handling.

Answer (score -2):

You can't execute TypeScript in a worker thread. The `pool.exec` method accepts either a static JavaScript function or a path to a JavaScript file with the same function.

Here is a quote from the [workerpool readme](https://github.com/josdejong/workerpool#offload-functions-dynamically):

> Note that both function and arguments must be static and stringifiable, as they need to be sent to the worker in a serialized form. In case of large functions or function arguments, the overhead of sending the data to the worker can be significant.

I'm trying to make this work with TypeScript. Possible ways to resolve this are:

- write a worker function in TypeScript, compile it to a separate bundle with any bundler, and then pass the path to the compiled file to the `pool.exec`. I managed to make this work but the only thing that I'm not satisfied with is that with this solution you can't use nodemon (if you use it)
- use a JS wrapper that compiles the TS source code and executes it using [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node). Then pass the path to that wrapper to the `pool.exec` function. This solution won't work with bundlers

Comment: As described in the issue, multiple lines in the worker thread were running just fine - and it just stopped running at one point. Clearly I already knew to transpile from TypeScript to JavaScript. This is why I didn't mention TypeScript in the issue title. My issue was that my worker thread was throwing an unhandled error.

Comment: @stevendesu Let me explain it in other words. If you transpiled your example it wouldn't work. You need to pass an independent module to the worker thread. In your example, you're passing the `processData` function that depends on the Axios. The `workerpool` serializes the `processData` function and passes it as text to a worker thread. It doesn't have any imports of Axios. That's why I suggested you to move your function to a separate module, compile it to a separate bundle and then pass the bundle to the `workerpool`

Comment: @stevendesu Here is how the `workerpool` serializes your function ([source code](https://github.com/josdejong/workerpool/blob/e5f2fb4798349d7f97a4b77b7f83f9e8f9722291/src/Pool.js#L138))
```else if (typeof method === 'function') {
    // send stringified function and function arguments to worker
    return this.exec('run', [String(method), params]);
  }```

It takes the `processData` function and makes a string from it. So a worker knows nothing about Axios